# Group objects by equality

Tags: c#

I have a collection of objects which I would like to compare for equality using a method which looks like this:

bool AreEqual(MyObject O1, MyObject O2);

What would be the most performance friendly way of grouping all equal objects? The obvious answer would be to compare every object with all the other objects in the collection but this would rather hurt the performance ( N ^ N, I believe).

Could the LINQ group by operator offer a solution?

EDIT:

I should perhaps have named MyObject TheirObject as I cannot modify its implementation (and it doesn't implement IComparable). This means I'll probably use ICR's solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to compare every object to every other object, you need to compare every object with every group (e.g. the first item in the group) and create a new group if it doesn't match any (or if it's the first item).

The might look something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Group<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    IList<IList<T>> groups = new List<IList<T>>();

    foreach (T t in items)
    {
        bool foundGroup = false;

        foreach (IList<T> group in groups)
        {
            Debug.Assert(group.Count() >= 1);
            if (group[0].Equals(t))
            {
                group.Add(t);
                foundGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!foundGroup)
        {
            IList<T> newGroup = new List<T>() { t };
            groups.Add(newGroup);
        }
    }

    foreach (IList<T> group in groups)
    {
        yield return group;
    }
}
```

This is, of course, already done for you in Linq, which people have outlined above how to use. I just wanted to demonstrate that the algorithm can be a little better than comparing every item to every item.

N.B. The algorithm relies on the assumption that the equality relationship is transitive -- i.e. if a is equal to b, and b is equal to c, then a is equal to c. Though I'm not quite sure how you would group non-transitive items.

Comment: Thank you for your sample. With your permission, I would like to use it in my project.
The final couple of lines are especially interesting. What benefit does the final loop offer over a simple "return groups;" ?

Comment: Like I say, I would still recommend the LINQ solution. It's doing pretty much the same thing, but it's already written for you. The reason I gave the sample was so you can see how such an algorithm might work.

The purpose of the final lines are because I like to return the most general type applicable -- in this case IEnumerable's. But in order to construct them you need to use IList's to have the Add method. C# currently can't work out how to turn an IEnumerable<IList<T>> into an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> so you need to yield each group manually.

The benefit is that it compiles :)

Comment: This is really not a good implementation, because it is O(n^2). Please use the existing `GroupBy` Linq extension method.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [IComparable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(VS.71).aspx) for MyObject class and then try grouping it, for example as it is done [here](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/04/linq-group-by-syntax-for-grouping-on.html)  or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx) if you are planning on using LINQ. [Here](http://nayyeri.net/icomparer-vs-iequalitycomparer) is an example using IComparer and IEqualityComparer

I would go with LINQ for comparing all the elements.If you are trying to get a list of distinct object I would do it this way (pseudocode)

1. Implement IEqualityComparer, say ObjectEqualityComparer implements IEqualityComparer
2. var result = sourceList.Distinct(an instance of objectEqualityComparer)