# LINQ Distinct and IEquality

Tags: linq-to-sql

How would I specify the id field of an object in a list of objects as the disctinction?

Selections.Distinct();

Answer (score 0):

You can create an equality comparer by implementing the `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` interface. You then pass your `ConcreteEqualityComparer` to `Distinct()`:

```
Selections.Distinct(new ConcreteEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: If he's using LINQ to SQL (which is how he's tagged this, though his code does look more like LINQ to Objects), in which case this won't work, because the equality comparer can't be translated to SQL.  (It will work in LINQ to Objects, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Answer (score 0):

IEqualityComparer  [sample implementation](http://nayyeri.net/icomparer-vs-iequalitycomparer). Shameless [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855462/group-objects-by-equality/1855520#1855520) to my answer for one similar SO question

Answer (score 0):

You may also override the methods Equals and GetHashCode methods of the class of the instances you are trying to filter.